# Is Dictionary.ContainsKey() any better than FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, lookup

I know, nothing one million of anything's gonna be performant. But I'm needing that piece o' knowledge right now.

I have a Dictionary and a string[]. The boolean in the dictionary is just to fill the space. Let's imagine that as an Inventory System just to make things easier.

In this inventory, I wanna check if I already had gotten one item. So what I'd do is:

```
if (dic.ContainsKey(item_id)) // That could be a TryGetValue() as well.
{
    // Do some logic.
}
```

But would it be better to just have an array?

```
if (array.FirstOrDefault(a => a = item_id))
{
    // Do magic.
}
```

I mean, which would perform better in that specific case?

I know, that's a silly question, but when you can have over one million (or over nine thousand, for the DBZ fans out there xD) checks, things can get pretty heavy, especially for mobile, VR and others with similar performance.

Plus, I just want my users to have the best experience with my Inventory (a.k.a. no lag), so I often take stuff like that in consideration.

Comment: Its worth noting that if you just want the lookup behaviours of keys in dictionary and don't care about values then a `Hashset<T>` is more suitable.

Comment: Using an array the average time to get data is N/2.  With a dictionary that uses a binary hash the average time to get data is Log2(N).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two tradeoffs here space and time.

A Dictionary is a relatively heavy weight structure compared to an array.

The lookup time in a Dictionary (or a HashSet) if basically independant of the number of entries O(1), while with the array it increases linearly O(N).

So there is a certain number of items where the Dictionary (or HashSet) begins to be considerably faster. And 1 million is certainly above this threshold.